# Postgresql: Allowing duplicates from same upload, but not from the next one

Tags: postgresql

I need to allow duplicates which are uploaded from the same file but if same values are uploaded from different file then these values needs to be marked as duplicates.
example:

```
fileId value status
1      100   SUCCESS
1      100   SUCCESS
2      100   DUPLICATE
3      100   DUPLICATE
3      200   SUCCESS
```

The idea was to lock somehow inserts for similar values to avoid race conditions, but in Postgres it seems not a very easy solution. 
Anyone has some ideas about how this could be implemented in a clean and nice way?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Unique index is fileId, value, status WHERE status != DUPLICATE, but I miss the fileId part to allow the insertions from the same file but not from other ones

Comment: Are you looking for a constraint that prevents that, or for a SQL query that returns the result you have shown?

Comment: @Tony94 nope it actually the result that I want and I asked it for this reason. Therefore is kind of hard to use a unique index in this case

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name constraint would be enough just to spot duplicates, but it seems not a usable for such case. SQL query that returns it it's easy but then we are not sure about the race conditions. So if I will query it do the checks and insert while I am doing the checks some other upload could insert duplicates (or until I commit and do some other work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define such a constraint using [exclusion constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)

For the following example to work, you need to [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the extension [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html)

```
create table uploads
(
  fileid integer,
  value integer
);

alter table uploads 
   add constraint unique_value 
   exclude using gist (value with =, fileid with <>);
```

So the following inserts will work:

```
insert into uploads values (1, 100);
insert into uploads values (2, 200);
insert into uploads values (1, 100);
```

But this one would fail:

```
insert into uploads values (2, 100);
```

with the error message:

```
ERROR: conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "unique_value"
  Detail: Key (value, fileid)=(100, 2) conflicts with existing key (value, fileid)=(100, 1).
```

Comment: This was the initial idea with normal unique index, but we were not able to add it as we don't have a reference, so we were thinking to do it like this:
create unique index uq_table_excluded_duplicate_status
  on table (name, value)
  where (status <> 'DUPLICATE' AND fileId <> not_sure_what_value_goes_here);

Comment: we opted for a different solution, we will keep the same index and will catch the duplicates in the code side and check the fileid that we are using, if it is the same we will update the value with some counter (to avoid hitting the unique index), otherwise it will be a duplicate. But still big thanks for your solution, we will still consider it as it seems to be cleaner